# HPLIP (downloaded from HP) won't run

Tags: drivers, printing, hplip

- My OS = Ubuntu 16.04
- My printer = HP Photosmart 5520

HPlip was working perfectly until I reinstalled Ubuntu 16.04 (for reasons unrelated to this problem).  HPLIP downloaded and extracted but won't run / work.

I can see it in the Downloads folder but can't get it to run.

What can I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install hplip from Ubuntu repositories instead.

```
sudo apt-get install hplip-gui
```

Hopefully, this will work.

Comment: Fantastic!  That did it!  First had to restart the pc and then, there it was, "HPLIP Toolbox" in the Dash.  I am very grateful for you help and advice and time - truly appreciated. Joo Nice, you are a total STAR !  Duncan

Answer (score 2):

Don't upgrade to version 3.17.9, stick with the version that comes from Ubuntu.

Had an old HP laserjet 1000 installed which is very cheap to run if you have many pages to print. It only worked with HPLIP, no other printer driver did the trick.

Then HP device manager suggested to upgrade and I did. Result was that HP device manager could no longer be started and the printer was of course no longer detected.

Next issue with HPLIP is that GScan2 (I use another printer from Canon for scanning) throws an error each time you start GScan2. Looks like HPLIP claims itself responsible for each printer, even if not supposed to be the driver of choice.

HP wrote a piece of crap not properly working on Ubuntu 16.04. Shame for them not to support Linux by default.