# Install HPLIP does not accept root password

Tags: drivers, software-installation, printing, hp, hplip

I am running in my shell:

`./hplip-3.18.7.run`

Then it wants me to enter the root password, but does not accepting it!

[image]

Anybody know what this is?

If I run the script with sudo `sudo ./hplip-3.18.7.run`
, then it tells me at some step in the installation process: `warning: hp-systray should not be run as root/superuser.`

I am using Ubuntu 18.04:

```
NAME="Ubuntu"
VERSION="18.04.1 LTS (Bionic Beaver)"
ID=ubuntu
ID_LIKE=debian
PRETTY_NAME="Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS"
VERSION_ID="18.04"
HOME_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://help.ubuntu.com/"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/"
PRIVACY_POLICY_URL="https://www.ubuntu.com/legal/terms-and-policies/privacy-policy"
VERSION_CODENAME=bionic
UBUNTU_CODENAME=bionic
```

This what the installer outputs at the beginning:

[image]

Comment: Ubuntu has no root password. Did you try `sudo ./hplip-3.18.7.run` ?

Comment: The I get `warning: hp-systray should not be run as root/superuser`

Comment: Any reason to not use the version from the repo? `sudo apt-get install hplip-gui`. [See this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/888770/hplip-downloaded-from-hp-wont-run?rq=1).

Comment: How can I uninstall the one I have installed?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to install latest HPLIP on my Ubuntu to support my HP printer and/or scanner?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) Also please make sure that you really need binary version from HP site. It is very likely that your printer is supported in `hplip-` packages from repository.

Comment: @RoVo Have installed it now from the repo, it doesn't start :-/ this is so annoying :-/

Comment: Which version of Ubuntu is this?

Comment: It is version 18.04.

Comment: Please add output of `cat /etc/os-release` to the question. And please remove comments [on other topic](https://askubuntu.com/a/1056078/66509) (it is not related to your original problem with permissions).

Comment: OK, but all comments are already removed. thanks for the help

Comment: I asked about /etc/os-release because of the fact that hplip-installer have hardcoded `sudo` auth mechanism for Ubuntu (and even Mint). Please run installer again and insert text starting with "Distro appears to be" to the question. I can't guess why it tries to use `su` instead of `sudo`. Is it possible that you are running Ubuntu-derivative (ElementaryOS or something)?

Comment: Please add output of the following commands to the question: `python -c "import platform;print platform.dist()[0]"`, `lsb_release -i | cut -f 2`, `cat /etc/issue | awk '{print $1}' | head -n 1`.

Comment: Both command lines output `Ubuntu`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/82476/discussion-between-n0rbert-and-saitam).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

## Analysis

From hplip source-code we can learn the following about auth. Auth is performed in [base/password.py](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/hplip/blob/debian/master/base/password.py) file.

The main `AUTH_TYPES` are for:

- Debian - `su`
- Ubuntu - `sudo`

During chat session and in comments we have discovered interesting moments:

- the first check is made python [platform module](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/hplip/blob/debian/master/base/password.py#L79). On Ubuntu it should return `"Ubuntu"`.
- [second](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/hplip/blob/debian/master/base/password.py#L84) distro check - `lsb_release -i | cut -f 2` returns `"Ubuntu"`
- [third](https://salsa.debian.org/printing-team/hplip/blob/debian/master/base/password.py#L88) distro check - `cat /etc/issue | awk '{print $1}' | head -n` returns `"Ubuntu"`.

But OP has installed Anaconda in home folder, and added this directory to the path. And what is interesting - in such case `python -c "import platform;print platform.dist()[0]"` returns `"Debian"` (**!!!**) on distro check. So installer tried to use `su`. But *root* account is disabled on Ubuntu by default, so problem arises (`"Please enter the root/superuser password:"` instead of `"Please enter the sudoer (%s)'s password: "`).

## Conclusion

Always check your `$PATH` variable for Python versions.
Many software in Ubuntu depend on Python. APT does not know about Anaconda, so system may have unpredictable behaviour with third-party `python`s and `pip`s. I can recommend to exclude third-party `python`s from `$PATH` variable.

Then binary hplip installer should work normally. And you can follow [my instruction](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1056077/how-to-install-latest-hplip-on-my-ubuntu-to-support-my-hp-printer-and-or-scanner) then.

Comment: If your issue is with Anaconda, as @n0rbert suggested, you can just temporarily turn conda off with 'conda deactivate'

Comment: `conda deactivate` is the most straight-forward way to solve this issue

Comment: but still issues with pyqt5, see [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1246680/some-python-packages-could-not-be-installed-during-hplip-3-20-5-installing-on-ub)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I am from the Czech Republic and my password contained some special characters which are not available in the English alphabet (ě, š). What fixed the issue was to temporarily change the password so that it does not contain these characters. After that, the password was finally accepted and the rest of the installation finished without any other issues.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue differently
As an Ubuntu user (no root password)

```
me@mycomputer:~$ sudo -s
[sudo] password for me:
root@computer:~#
```

After this, the installer didn't ask me for any password.

Comment: The installer tells me "You are running the installer as root. It is highly recommended that you run the installer as error: a regular (non-root) user. Do you still wish to continue?". Did you get the same?

Comment: no, because I tried to do it as a sudo user and not a root user.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/291454/difference-between-sudo-user-and-root-user